# Smartgit error: "Push Error Not all refs have been pushed"

Tags: git, bitbucket, repository, git-commit

I am using Smartgit with a repository hosted from 'bitbucket.org'.

I got this error message:

> Error Not all refs have been pushed

And changes are not committed.  What does this error mean?

Here is the complete log for my latest action around this repo:

```
LF will be replaced by CRLF in apps/frontend/modules/persona/templates/indexSuccess.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
LF will be replaced by CRLF in apps/frontend/modules/persona/templates/indexSuccess.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
LF will be replaced by CRLF in apps/frontend/modules/persona/templates/indexSuccess.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
LF will be replaced by CRLF in apps/frontend/modules/persona/templates/indexSuccess.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
LF will be replaced by CRLF in apps/frontend/modules/persona/templates/indexSuccess.php.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
[master 3c24f17] Modificada la plantilla, añadidos enlaces para editar/eliminar
 1 file changed, 8 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
'master' rejected (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://reynierpm@bitbucket.org/reynierpm/hisclinicas.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried the suggestion from @niculare I did a `git pull` but now I get these errors:

> Rebase: rebase failed (return code 1)     Eliminados ficheros de BD
>   antiguos e inservibles    # Please enter the commit message for your
>   changes. Lines starting   # with '#' will be ignored, and an empty
>   message aborts the commit.    # Not currently on any branch.  # You are
>   currently rebasing.   #   (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase
>   --continue")  #   # Changes to be committed:  #   (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)     #   # modified:   database.sql  # modified:
>   hisclinicas.sql   #   [detached HEAD 277cd27] Eliminados ficheros de BD
>   antiguos e inservibles     2 files changed, 1155 deletions(-)      rewrite
>   database.sql (100%)    rewrite hisclinicas.sql (100%)     Rebasing (3/10)
>     Rebasing (4/10)     Rebasing (5/10)     Rebasing (6/10)     error: could not
>   apply 7b8d48e... Eliminadas las tablas y los modulos ciudades y
>   parroquias (se dejo solo en Estados -> Municipios)    When you have
>   resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".   If you prefer to
>   skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.     To check out the
>   original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".  LF will
>   be replaced by CRLF in
>   lib/filter/doctrine/base/BaseHclinicaFormFilter.class.php.    The file
>   will have its original line endings in your working directory.    LF
>   will be replaced by CRLF in
>   lib/filter/doctrine/base/BasePersonaFormFilter.class.php.     The file
>   will have its original line endings in your working directory.    LF
>   will be replaced by CRLF in
>   lib/form/doctrine/base/BaseHclinicaForm.class.php.    The file will have
>   its original line endings in your working directory.  LF will be
>   replaced by CRLF in lib/form/doctrine/base/BasePersonaForm.class.php.
>     The file will have its original line endings in your working
>   directory.    LF will be replaced by CRLF in
>   lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseHclinica.class.php.   The file will have
>   its original line endings in your working directory.  Could not pick
>   7b8d48e4229e423994f0cb6148bfb35c1e1c744d

What does the error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: SmartGit does a `git pull --rebase` by default, can you try aborting the rebase and turning off the rebase option and attempting the pull again?

Comment: @SteveBuzonas I confused, this morning I was working at office with the same repo and all the above errors happen, so I get the copy saved in a flash drive and then in my home and working with the same repo I replace all the newest files and did a COMMIT, in my home didn't fail but in my office at work still the same problem, what's wrong?

Comment: The issue is that the push fails because your history is behind that of master. For some reason SmartGit made `pull --rebase` the standard pull mechanism. When you pulled it went into a rebase that failed because of `database.sql` and `hisclinicas.sql`, the files were both 100% rewritten. Whether you rebase or merge, you will need to be able to do a fast forward merge onto the remote master for it to allow you to push.  `git checkout origin/master && git merge master && git push HEAD:master` may be the most simplified route if you are new to git.

Comment: @SteveBuzonas thanks for your reply, I don't know how to do this to a remote server like Bitbucket but you teach me something new. Can you please write this in a answer so I can accept your reply as the question solution? What I do is delete complety the repo at my office and then clone again from the master but as said before your solution teach me something new for me